# How to do this problem without using infinitesimal?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, nonstandard-analysis

> A rod of **linear charge density** a of length h, What will be the
>   electric field at **an axial point at a distance x from end of the
>   rod** (the end at which the origin is chosen for defining charge
>   density function)?

Please solve the problem **formally** **without using** non standard analysis, neither **infinitesimals** as it is a part of non standard analysis?

The problem is off course trivial (using differentials).

That is :-

Consider the charge in infintesimal element $dx$ at a distance $x$ from the end, then electric field due this charge at a distance $x$ from the endpoint is $$dF= \frac{\rho}{4\pi \epsilon ((h-x)^2) }dx$$

Thus the net electric field due the full rod is given by

> $$F=\int_{0}^{h}\frac{\rho}{4\pi \epsilon ((h-x)^2) }dx$$

which can easily be found out.

But this is not my question.

> The sole purpose of mine to raise the question is to do the problem in
>   a **mathematically formal manner without** using differentials ,in the
>   realm of standard analysis .

Someone said to me that the problem could be done in a formal way even **without** using infinitesimals so being curious I posted for help?

*The main need for the question is to increase the understanding of formal mathematics in physics.*

Comment: I think a more formal argument would use limits instead of infinitesimals. You would have to write an expression for the field $\Delta F$ due to a *small but finite* element $\Delta x$, and then find the limit of $\frac {\Delta F}{\Delta x}$ as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$. This would involve introducing some additional terms which tend to $0$ in the limit - this is the part that the less formal argument misses out.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the question the so called (error term )$/\Delta x=0$ as $\Delta x$ tends to zero , **but how?**

Comment: @gandalf61 I think that the question requires more assumptions which may become evident as one writes the equation?

Answer (score 3):

Do you realize that your question is **not** a mathematics question? So how can you ask for a formal solution? That is precisely the problem here; you have **not formally defined** "rod" and "linear charge density" and "electric field", besides other terms. Furthermore, you need to prove **formal axioms** governing the electric field. After you do so in a natural way, then it should be obvious that the solution is a trivial consequence of the axioms, because the **integral** is exactly how we **define** the net electric field at each point in euclidean space!

Think first about the far simpler physical notion of mass of an object, given the density function. There is no way to derive the mass as an integral of the density, without assuming it or something equivalent. After all, this is how we define the density function in the first place, namely the limit of mass divided by volume of a region surrounding the point whose diameter goes to zero, and this would imply the integral.

In cases such as the charge density and electric field, I think it's fair to say that the classical viewpoint would simply **axiomatize** electric field as the integral of the charge density, because that's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Anyway, the definition of electric field in sense of mathematics , atleast for this problem is the for a charge $q$ in 3 dimension space the electric field in the vector $$\vec F= \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon (r^3) } \vec r$$ taking the charge to be at the origin.

Comment: The definition of linear charge density at a point on the rod (a line in terms of mathematics) is a integrable function $\rho (x)$ such that the $$q=\int_{0}^{x} \rho(t)dt $$ where q is the charge in present in the range of 0 to x on the line (rod) for $0<x<=h$  and $\rho (x)=0 $ for $x>h$

Comment: @BijayanRay: What you're stating is the definition of electric field of a **point charge**, which is **irrelevant** to your question where you have a continuous charge density function.

Comment: That's why it is necessary for you to attempt to be precise, as you tried to in your above comments, so that it would be clear that you haven't provided a formal definition of "electric field given charge density function".

Comment: By the way, "rod" in mathematics has thickness. I know you meant line, based on the rest of your question, but don't use "rod" if you mean line. And I'm not criticizing the intention behind your question. I'm just trying to make clear that it really comes down to proper definitions, before the question becomes sensible, and likely trivial.

Comment: Yes that is my question , thus the electric field definition is not valid for continuous charge definition , but if it is true why have not a general definition of electric field stated in physics?

Comment: Not only in this case , much of the laws in physics say the Newton Law Of Gravitation , are given for point objects but how can it be extended to continuous distribution without loss of rigor?

Comment: This makes the question important to me.

Comment: @BijayanRay: Well, as I explained in my post, any mathematician who wants to rigorously define electric field given charge density will likely do so **via** the integral. You **cannot** extend a definition that does not apply willy nilly, without loss of rigour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89147/discussion-between-user21820-and-bijayan-ray).

Comment: For reference, [Mark S. commented in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48829137#48829137) that indeed Gurtin's Continuum Mechanics text (and perhaps other texts) does the sort of "define many things by integrals" thing, doesn't justify those sorts of axioms, but gets to conclusions rigorously from them.